# Entity handling items added to database but SaveChanges fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How would you handle or clear items added to the database when SaveChanges fails.

Example

```
db.MyTable.Add(MyModel);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If `db.SaveChanges()` fails, what happens to the data added by `db.MyTable.Add(MyModel)`?

Do I need to clear out these added items? If so how?

When the service attempts to update an item I may have removed manually, it throws a constraint issue as it should.

It seems like I someone need to undo these items that were added after this issue so they aren't trying to be added over and over again throwing the same error as it's doing.

Comment: You can detach inserted entity from `DbContext`

Comment: Wouldn't they just continue to build up but not be updated in SaveChanges if I just keep detaching them or would that not be the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `SaveChanges()` call inside a `try...catch` block:

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (DbEntityValidationResult item in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = item.Entry;

        //...

        // Rollback changes

        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

The above code checks the `State` property of the `DbEntityEntry` causing the error. If the current State is Added, it is changed to Detached.
 or just overriding it.

Or you can override the `SaveChanges()` call and do the same thing.

Comment: Would I have a build up of detached entries? Would it work or be better in the catch to use `db.MyTable.Remove(MyModel)` or would that not make a difference?

Comment: In this case, changes are discarded. So you may give another chance to the user to make the changes and then call `SaveChanges()` again.

Comment: Had to change it to DbUpdateException, will monitor memory usage to make sure but so far it's working.